# How to display newline in TimelineItem control's text property?

Tags: sapui5

We have a SAPUI5 timeline control, where we are showing the comments coming from server.

The issue is, if the comments contain a newline `\n`, then the Timeline control is not able to display the text in newline. Instead, it introduces space wherever `\n` is present.
We have tried formatting `\n` to unicode character also but that also didn't worked. Timeline control aggregates TimelineItem.
The control we are using is: https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.suite.ui.commons.TimelineItem

Code snippet can be found at:
https://jsbin.com/kuluyehilu/edit?html,output

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65767922/5846045. It was a bug in UI5.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a line break to text in UI5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148073/how-to-add-a-line-break-to-text-in-ui5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inspected your example and came up with the following solution.

Since the text is embedded in a `<span>`, all unnecessary whitespace will be trimmed. What you can do is telling the span (via CSS) that it should display the whitespace anyway.

If you don't have a CSS file in your project yet, create one. Then add the following lines

```
div.sapSuiteUiCommonsTimelineItemShellBody>span {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

This should do the trick.

JSBin: https://jsbin.com/feladeneso/1/edit?html,output

Comment: This is super way to achieve the linebreak. According to documentation white-space: pre -  Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will only wrap on line breaks. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the rendered element, you will see it actually put in the break:

```
<span id="__item0-realtext">x
y</span>
```

...but did not convert it to a `<br/>` tag. You cannot add the tag yourself since it will be escaped, either. Maybe you can try to override the renderer, and convert any line breaks to html breaks

Comment: Yes, we also observed the same in the rendered element. Could you please provide more details on how we can override the renderer.

Comment: Never tried it myself yet, but maybe https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/91/f393916f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/content.htm gives some pointers