# How to add a line break to text in UI5?

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5, newline, line-breaks

The escape character `\n` and Unicode character `\u000a` will only work in JavaScript. However, I'm trying to add a line break in XML view as below. But doesn't work:

```xml
<u:TimelineItem text="First Line\n SecondLine" />
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

New lines in text controls can be added with the following characters:

- #### **In XML** views or XML fragments:

  - *Line feed*: `&#10;` or `&#x0A;`.
  - **Recommended:*** In combination with *carriage return*: `&#13;&#10;` or `&#x0D;&#x0A;`.
- #### **In JS** or `i18n.properties` files:

  - *Line feed*: `\n` or `\u000a`.
  - **Recommended:*** In combination with *carriage return*: `\r\n` or `\u000d\u000a`.
  - Alternatively, consider using [*template literals*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of concatenating the above characters manually (i.e. simply replace `"..."` with `` `...` ``).
- Some UI5 controls allow the [HTML tag **`<br>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) (in XML: `&lt;br>`) out of the box:

  - `sap.m.MessageStrip` since UI5 v1.85: [API reference](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.MessageStrip), [Sample](https://jsbin.com/renocuq/edit?js,output)
  - `sap.m.FormattedText`: [API reference](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.FormattedText)

<sup>* See *[Issues with different newline formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Issues_with_different_newline_formats)*. It is recommended to use the combination with Carriage Return for most of the internet protocols.</sup>

Here is a UI5 demo with `sap.suite.ui.commons.TimelineItem`* and `sap.m.Text`:

```js
globalThis.onUI5Init = () => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
  "sap/m/Text",
], async (XMLView, Text) => {
  "use strict";
  
  const view = await XMLView.create({
    definition: `<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" height="100%">
      <App xmlns="sap.m" autoFocus="false">
        <Page showHeader="false" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
          <commons:TimelineItem xmlns:commons="sap.suite.ui.commons"
            text="Multiline supported&#10;in Timeline items (XML)"
          />
          <HBox id="myBox" justifyContent="SpaceAround">
            <Text
              text="This&#10;is&#x0A;a&#13;&#10;text (created in XML view)!"
              renderWhitespace="true"
            />
          </HBox>
        </Page>
      </App>
    </mvc:View>`,
  });
  
  const textCreatedInJS = new Text({
    renderWhitespace: true,
    text: "And this\nis\u000aanother\r\ntext (created in JS)!",
  });
  view.byId("myBox").addItem(textCreatedInJS);
  view.placeAt("content");
});
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://ui5.sap.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m,sap.suite.ui.commons"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-oninit="onUI5Init"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody"></body>
```

* The `TimelineItem` had a bug in earlier versions of UI5 preventing multilines. According to their changelog for 1.44.5:

> [FIX] sap.suite.ui.commons.Timeline: Rendering of multiline text improved

In case the control `sap.m.Text` is used, keep in mind to enable the properties `renderWhitespace` and `wrapping` in order render the new lines in the DOM.

---

## For UI5 Control Developers

Rendering text in DOM can be achieved via the [API `.text(/*...*/)`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.RenderManager#methods/text) from the `RenderManager`. That API, however, doesn't necessarily apply newlines even if the text contains the above mentioned line break characters. In that case, the [`white-space`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop) property `pre-line` can be applied to the control's CSS style:

```css
.myControlWithText {
  /* ...; */
  white-space: pre-line; /* Allows line break characters to be applied */
}
```

Answer (score -2):

> You can use the embeddedControl aggregation to use the text control
>   inside TimelineItem

```
<u:TimelineItem>
      <u:embeddedControl><Text text="First Line\n SecondLine"></Text></u:embeddedControl>
</u:TimelineItem>
```