# how to start a new line in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

//create page 4 content of Iviews

```
                    var page4 = new sap.m.Page("page4",{
                    title : "Iviews",
                    content : new sap.m.Text({
                    text : "An iView (integrated view) is a logical portal content building block representing a visual application or part thereof.iViews let you extend the reach of your portal to any available information resource, regardless of where it may be stored. The underlying architecture of iViews enables them to return up-to-the-minute information each time they are launched, from data sources as varied as:",
```

i want to start a new line in the text how to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a line break to text in UI5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148073/how-to-add-a-line-break-to-text-in-ui5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was /n or \n in your text string... Try one of those and let me know afterwards